# Running unpacked chrome extensions with chrome.extension.sendRequest

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

While I understand chrome.extension.sendRequest was superseded by chrome.extension.sendMessage , I have some old code which uses it and I wish to run it without making any changes.

While the standard installation works, when I try to load the unpacked extension it fails with error `sendRequest and onRequest are obsolete`

Is there a way I can have back compatibility for this specific case?

Comment: Why not just change the code?

Comment: I think you'd had to find and install an older version of Chrome.

Comment: this is a good question, does anyone know why it works in a packed extension but not in an unpacked one... its a bit confusing... also does anyone know if they plan to completely remove the deprecated calls at some point, and if so when?